# Spring Boot JPA: How to avoid creating multiple repositories for identical databases?

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My spring boot mvc project interacts with a database via a repository interface, which works nicely using Spring boot default configurations:

```
    spring:
       datasource:
       url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/some_schema
       username: 
       ...

    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"my.path.to.repository"})
    public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ....
```

Now depending on some runtime condition, I need to interact with an **identical** second database (same schema) in a separate location. The solutions I found all point to creating a separate repository package per datasource.

Since the databases are identical, however, is there an elegant way to avoid duplicating the repository package for each added datasource?

Comment: No, you have to duplicate.  I'd ask why you need another identical schema and what you think you're saving by being "elegant".

Comment: An "elegant" solution would be one that avoids code duplication if possible.

Comment: This is configuration.  There's no choice: You need configuration for each database you intend to use.  It's far more work to duplicate the schema than to write three lines of configuration.  Maybe you should eliminate the duplicate database.

Comment: What bothers me the most is the code duplication of the repository package

Comment: It feels like you are missing the point.  You are exercised about the code, but the database duplication is beyond question.  Voting to close.

Comment: @duffymo I think OP is talking about multi-tenancy, so this is a valid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a Spring [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html).

Roughly:

```
public class ChooseOneDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        if (***some runtime condition***) {
          return "dataSource1";
        } else {
          return "dataSource2";
        }
    }
}
```

And in your conguration:

```
@Bean 
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dataSource1")
DataSource dataSource1() {
 return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dataSource2")
DataSource dataSource2() {
 return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
 AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSource = new ChooseOneDataSource();
 Map<Object,Object> resolvedDataSources = new HashMap<>();
 resolvedDataSource.put("dataSource1", dataSource1());
 resolvedDataSource.put("dataSource2", dataSource2());
 dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource1()); // << default
 dataSource.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources);
 return dataSource;
}
```

For more info/examples:

http://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/Make-your-Spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/
https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/